# program which check perfect numbers - something gets wrong

Tags: c++, numbers

I have to write a function which gets a number, and prints all the perfect numbers that are smaller than the number given. If there are not any, the function prints an appropriate message.
The program I have just written is compiled well, but it's working only partially. If the input number is 5, for instance, for some reason I don't get any message that there are not perfect numbers in this range (=until 5) .

Can someone please explain to me what's wrong in this program?
I would appreciate any help!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
void check (int num, int & j);
void main()
{

 int num,j, count;

 cout << "List all the perfect numbers less than: ";
 cin >> num;

 check (num, j);
}


 void check (int num, int & j)
 {
     int i,sum, count=0;
 for(j=2;j<num;num++)
 {
     sum=0;
   for(i=1;i<j;i++)
   { 
      if(j%i == 0)
      sum += i; 
   }

    if(sum == j)
    {cout << j <<endl; 
    count+=1;
    }
 }   

 if (count==0)
     cout<<"there are no perfect numbers"<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: As an aside, there are only 5 perfect numbers that would fit inside a 32-bit `int` and 8 that would fit inside 64-bit.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but it still does not answer my problem :(

Comment: Why do you pass in an uninitialized `int j` by reference to `void check()`? Considering you set `j=2`inside your check function and there is no recursion inside void check() why is j even passed in?

Comment: @TOM1992 I realise that. I guess I was trying to show that attempting to list perfect numbers like this is eye-wateringly inefficient.

Comment: hmmm....so how would you write a program checking what I need?

Answer (score 7):

There is an infinite loop in your code:

```
for(j=2;j<num;num++)
```

I think it should be

```
for(j=2;j<num;j++)
```

Comment: I corrected that, but it still does not work.....

Comment: what do you mean not work, I test it, it seems ok to me..Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: for example, if the input is num=4, I am supposed to get a message that there are no perfect numbers in this range (from 2 to 4), but in the output I dont get any .

Comment: I do get the message `there are no perfect numbers` by just changing one line of your code...

Comment: what is your change? may you tell me?

Comment: I already post it. Change the for loop line since you are testing each j whether it is perfect number.

Comment: But I did change it....and still dont get a message...

Comment: have a look at this [link](http://ideone.com/jp2o8X)